# Incluir arquivos com URL amigável

Tags: php, include

Estou utilizando *URL amigável* em meu site, eu incluo os arquivos na `index.php` tudo corretamente, e ele funciona no meu *arquivo* `pages/register.php` certinho.

Só que quando eu acesso diretamente com a url `http://localhost/treinos/pages/register.php`

O servidor me acusa este erro:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Cadastro' not found in C:\wamp\www\treinos\pages\register.php on line 2
```

Este erro só ocorre se eu acesso diretamente o arquivo, ele normal incluindo com a *URL amigável* não acusa erro, alguém saberia por que raios isso está acontecendo... ?

Comment: qual o problema ? vc quer que, ao acessar o arquivo diretamente, funcione o include ou seja bloqueado?

Comment: Que funcione o include normalmente como se tivesse acessando normal!

Comment: mostre a regra de reescrita de url.. edite e inclua na pegunta

Comment: Resolvi incluindo no arquivo `"pages/register.php"` isso `require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/modules/Config.php");
require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/modules/class/Connection.class.php");
require_once(dirname(__DIR__)."/modules/class/Cadastro.class.php");`

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar o padrão [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) para autoload de classes.